# Makefile related issue

Tags: c++, makefile, gpu

I edited the question completely. I have found some things which does not make sense but it works. When I run make for the first time, I got below output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [targets] Error 1
```

But when I run make for the second time, the target file (multikernel-sim) is created. Here is also my Makefile

```
LEVEL=.
include $(LEVEL)/Makefile.common
all: subdirs targets
OBJECTS  = $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/launcher/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/launcher/mk-sched/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/launcher/stats/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/common/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/src/cuda-sim/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/src/cuda-sim/decuda_pred_table/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/src/gpgpu-sim/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/src/intersim2/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/src/ramulator_sim/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/src/*.o)
OBJECTS += $(wildcard ./kain_gpuwattch/*.o)

subdirs:
        $(MAKE) -C ./common
        $(MAKE) -C ./src
        $(MAKE) -C ./launcher
        $(MAKE) -C ./libcuda

targets: makedirs $(OBJECTS)
        $(CXX) $(CCFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -lz -lm -lpthread -o $(BIN_DIR)/multikernel-sim
.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -rf build/
        rm -rf lib/
        rm -rf bin/

makedirs:
        if [ ! -d $(BIN_DIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR); fi;
```

and Makefile.common

```
CUDA_VERSION_STRING:=$(shell $(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/bin/nvcc --version | awk '/release/ {print $$5;}' | sed 's/,//')
CUDART_VERSION:=$(shell echo $(CUDA_VERSION_STRING) | sed 's/\./ /' | awk '{printf("%02u%02u", 10*int($$1), 10*$$2);}')

# Compiler options
#CC=gcc
#CXX=g++
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5
CXX=/usr/bin/g++-5
MAKE=make

CCFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -std=c++0x -DCUDART_VERSION=$(CUDART_VERSION)
CCDEBUGFLAGS=-g -Wall -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -std=c++0x -DCUDART_VERSION=$(CUDART_VERSION)

BUILD_DIR = $(LEVEL)/build
LIB_DIR   = $(LEVEL)/lib
BIN_DIR   = $(LEVEL)/bin
```

It's a bit uncommon that I should make twice to get the final binary file. I assume there are missed object files during the first make. I really don't know how it works. Can somebody help me with this?

Note: there are a few sub-directories as below:

launcher/mk-sched

launcher/stats

src/cuda-sim

src/gpgpu-sim

src/gpuwatch

src/intersim2

src/ramulator-sim

Thank you

Comment: There's no `Makefile` in your question.

Comment: And no main() in his not posted program...

Comment: Please post the C++ code you have and the Makefile itself. Right now it looks like the problem is that your program does not have a `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)` anywhere.

Comment: @lionkor codes Added

Comment: @U.W. codes added

Comment: could you provide a note as to how your files are layed out in the project? i.e. which file contains main, which dependencies you have, and maybe a `tree` of the project structure?

Comment: Please, what is the name of the file with the main() ??

Comment: @U.W. The main is in launcher/launcher.cc

Answer (score 2):

When asking questions about link lines, please show the actual link line that caused the error, not just the last few error lines.  If you examine the link line, you'll almost certainly see the problem for yourself: there is no `launcher.o` in your link line.

Why is that?  Well, we can't say because that object file is supposed to be created by running make in the `launcher` subdirectory and we don't know what that makefile does or how it works.

You should investigate the output of your build, find out whether `launcher.o` is created or not, and if so where it is put.

There are various other issues here.

Most importantly, this is wrong:

```
OBJECTS=$(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/launcher/*.o)
OBJECTS+=$(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/launcher/mk-sched/*.o)
  ...
```

and the rest.  Why?  Because you are trying to use wildcard to get a list of objects *before the build is done* which means the first time through your build, this:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/multikernel-sim: makedirs $(OBJECTS)
```

will expand to zero object files and not have any prerequisites other than `makedirs`.

You should construct your list of object files based on the *sources*, which will always exist, then convert them in the makefile.  So something like:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard launcher/*.cc)
  ...
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.cc=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
```

Second, when running recursive makes you should *always* use the variable `$(MAKE)` and never use the raw command `make`.

In your `DEBUG_OBJECTS` all the lines except two use a `.g` extension; those two still use `.o`: Is that intentional?  Seems weird.

This if-statement is not needed:

```
if [ ! -d $(BIN_DIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR); fi;
```

The `-p` option to `mkdir` already exits with success if the directory exists so you can just write:

```
mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
```

Comment: I tend to frown on using `$(wildcard)` *at all*. Aside from it being a GNU-ism (which these days is a pretty weak criticism), its primary advantage is convenience, which it achieves at the cost of incurring an unnecessary risk of incorrectness.  According to me, sources and objects should either be designated explicitly or be generated by substitution reference.

Comment: I don't disagree, but not everyone thinks the same so... oh well.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I'm considering your hints and trying to figure out. In the meantime, as you said, I added the Makefile which is in the launcher sub-directory.